# Trying to calculate de equation for linear regression with numpy.polyfit but getting too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-regression

I'm expected to read a column "Horas Estudo" and a number(x) = 5.95 then calculate the y= **a**x + **b**.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/k3owtgaywmjhk66/fake-classrooms-correl03.csv?dl=1")

col = input()
x = round(float(input()),2)

(a,b) = np.polyfit(df[col],df["Nota Final"], deg=2)
print(a,b)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-81-7e077f926863> in <module>()
      7 x = round(float(input()),2)
      8 
----> 9 (a,b) = np.polyfit(df[col],df["Nota Final"], deg=2)
     10 print(a,b)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

np.polyfit returns the polynomial coefficients in the form of an **ndarray** and not a tuple. So put a single variable on the left and print it.
Also if you are trying to find a linear fit (y=ax+b), put the **deg=1** in the function call

Comment: Thanks for helping! I've changed **deg** and it worked but i didn't change the tuple and it worked with those 2 variables, when i search for  type(a,b)  prints **<class  'numpy.float64'>** so how this information helps me to understand that i can use tuple in this exercise?

Comment: I see, actually when you were putting deg=2 and it was throwing error because a polynomial of degree 2 will return 3 coefficients. In your case (deg=1), yes you can use tuple of 2 (a,b) since function will return only 2 polynomial coefficients.